# Get info of images after saving them using MediaStore in Android 10 & above

Tags: android, mediastore, android-10.0, scoped-storage

In my app, I am using the below code to allow users to select multiple images.

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = "image/*"
    }

startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE)
```

In `onActivityResult()`, I get the list of URIs which are converted to the list of Files. I am compressing these files and saving the bitmap using the below code.

```
private fun saveImage(bitmap: Bitmap?) {
    val imageName = "image_${UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 5)}"
    var uri: Uri? = null

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val relativeLocation =
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + getString(R.string.app_name)
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, imageName)
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png")
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativeLocation)
        }
        val contentResolver = context?.contentResolver
        var stream: OutputStream? = null
        try {
            val contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            uri = contentResolver?.insert(contentUri, contentValues)

            if (uri == null) throw IOException("Failed to create new MediaStore record.")
            stream = contentResolver?.openOutputStream(uri)
            if (stream == null) throw  IOException("Failed to get output stream.")
            if (bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream) == false) {
                throw IOException("Failed to save bitmap.")
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            if (uri != null) {
                contentResolver?.delete(uri, null, null)
            }
            throw e
        } finally {
            stream?.close()
        }
        contentValues.clear()
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
        contentResolver?.update(uri!!, contentValues, null, null)
    } else {
        var stream: OutputStream? = null
        try {
            val savePath =
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    .toString() + File.separator + getString(R.string.app_name)
            val file = File(savePath)

            if (!file.exists()) file.mkdir()
            val imageFile = File(savePath, "$imageName.png")
            stream = FileOutputStream(imageFile)
            bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw e
        } finally {
            stream?.close()
        }
    }
}
```

Once the compression is done, I am showing the user the list of compressed images along with its size before and after compression.

The problem is since I am getting a `File` below Android Q, I can easily extract information like the name and size of the compressed image. However, in Android Q and above, I don't get access to the File since the Bitmap is saved using MediaStore. Is there any easy and fast approach to get the name and the size of the saved Bitmap using MediaStore?

Comment: You are setting the name with DISPLAY_NAME so i dont understand why you ask how to determine the name.

Comment: `I get the list of URIs which are converted to the list of Files.` You can indeed do that below Q. But it is a bad method. With Q you cannot convert uri to file path.

Comment: @blackapps Yes, I can get the display name directly but what about the size of the saved image?

Comment: You can query the media store for it using the obtained uri. DISPLAY_NAME, MIME_TYPE, FILE_SIZE, LAST_MODIFIED and such things.